# Graph Intersection Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a 2D graph where each node represents a point in a 2D plane and each edge is a line connecting the 2 points. I'm using this to represent user sketches in a drawing interface.

How can I find intersections on such graph and create new nodes and edges representing the new topology?

I've seen the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm, but I think it only gives me the intersection points. Is there a complete algorithm for this, or should I adapt the Bentley-Ottmann?